# How to display eclipse annotations (Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors>Annotations) in the "Problems/Errors/Markers" view?

Tags: eclipse

When editing an html file, eclipse display useful annotations on the right margin, like "Invalid tag location" or "unknown tag", but it will be useful to see them with in any tab like "Problems", "Markers" or "Errors" without have to open each html file and put the mouse on the annotation to see the description.

Comment: Do you mean the `Problems` view

Comment: Can be to `Problems` view, or any other view

Answer (score 0):

When a problem is on an annotation but not in the Markers tab, validate the file can make it appear there.